# JS calendar - use DOM attributes or JS objects?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm building a JS calendar app that allows users to select a single date or range of dates across a calendar that can span many months or years.

The way it's currently set up, each calendar table cell has its date set as an attribute.

I have a listener delegate handling all the clicks from the divs that hold the calendar tables. The handler reads the "date" attribute of the clicked cell, then uses that information to update the calendar.

My question is, is this a bad way to use DOM attributes? I know that accessing the DOM is much slower than a JS object, but we're talking about hundreds of calendar dates, so my feeling is that having a JS object with an attached div for each one is overkill.

Comment: DOM elements are objects. You can add custom properties to them.

Comment: For HTML5 compliance, custom attributes are supposed to have a "data-" prefix. HTML4 doesn't require a prefix, but does require an ATTLIST in the DOCTYPE tag (Google it if you're curious). I doubt you'll ever have any problems if you ignore the standards in this case, though. One advantage I can think of to using attributes instead of js properties is that the former can be targeted by CSS attribute selectors. Another is that you don't have to worry about some future spec implementing a property with the same name as yours. If neither of those matter to you, properties would be more convenient

Comment: If you are only adding a single attribute to the DOM element as an index (id, date) to the underlying data that seems both common and reasonable.  If you were to start adding many attributes to avoid backing data then I suspect that's going to have some 'cost'.  Using attributes is going to add overhead for complex types that need transforming on each access.  As with most such conundrums, benchmarking might be a good way to find out the tradeoffs.